# Leap motion -> Node.js -> Arduino. Error: SerialPort not open repost

Tags: node.js, arduino, leap-motion

I've been trying to connect my leap with my arduino using node.js, following [this guide](http://xseignard.github.io/2013/06/25/interfacing-leap-motion-with-arduino-thanks-to-nodejs/), but I keep getting this error:

```
1442170022060 Device(s) /dev/cu.usbmodem1421  
1442170022073 Connected /dev/cu.usbmodem1421  
1442170025540 Repl Initialized  
>> events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: Serialport not open.
    at SerialPortFactory.SerialPort.write (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/serialport/serialport.js:288:17)
    at Board.analogWrite (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/firmata/lib/firmata.js:643:18)
    at Board.servoWrite (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/node_modules/firmata/lib/firmata.js:690:20)
    at Servo.Controllers.Standard.servoWrite.value (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/servo.js:108:17)
    at Servo.to (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/johnny-five/lib/servo.js:315:12)
    at Object._move [as move] (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/lib/joint.js:28:10)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/proj.js:41:26)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at Receiver.ontext (/Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/ws/lib/WebSocket.js:816:10)
    at /Users/Kenny/Documents/src/node_modules/ws/lib/Receiver.js:477:18
```

This is my code

```
var five = require('johnny-five'),
WebSocket = require('ws'),
ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:6437'),
board = new five.Board(),
LeapFrame = require('./lib/leapFrame'),
Joint = require('./lib/joint'),
frame,
i = 0;
```

board.on('ready',function() {

```
     var servoPitch = new Joint({

        minPos: 50,
        maxPos: 100,
        pin: 11,
        range: [70,100]
     });

     var servoNod = new Joint({
        minPos: 0,
        maxPos: 100,
        pin: 10,
        range: [70, 130]
     })

     var servoRoll = new Joint({
        minPos: -60,
        maxPos: 430,
        pin: 9,
        range: [0,200]
     })

     ws.on('message',function(data,flags) {
           i++;
           if (i%3 == 0) {
            frame = new LeapFrame(data);
            if(frame.valid) {
            servoPitch.move(frame.deltaHandFinger.y);
           servoRoll.move(200 - frame.palmPosition.x);
           servoNod.move(frame.palmPosition.y);

            }
           i = 0;
           }
           });



     });
```

I uploaded standardfirmata onto my arduino

im able to use servoRoll fine, but the other two are giving me the error

Anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: would each of move functions work if you commented out the other two?

Comment: nope i get the same error regardless